# Is it possible to post process iPhone GPS data?

Tags: iphone, post-processing

Is there software available for post processing iPhone based GPS data?

I want to post process a set of coordinate values to correct for measurement errors. There is a NOAA CORS base station about 40 miles from the site I collected the coordinates.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you'd like to do?

Comment: I want to post process a set of coordinate values to correct for measurement errors.  There is a NOAA CORS base station about 40 miles from the site I collected the coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

**Apples GPS Core Location description**

> The Core Location framework lets you determine the current location or
>   heading associated with a device. The framework uses the available
>   hardware to determine the user’s position and heading. You use the
>   classes and protocols in this framework to configure and schedule the
>   delivery of location and heading events. You can also use it to define
>   geographic regions and monitor when the user crosses the boundaries of
>   those regions.

Example code:

```
@interface CoreLocationController : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locMgr;
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locMgr;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end
```

Comprehensive Tutorial:

http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/

Comment: This answer is not useful. Please see the description of CORS http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS/